# Getting unknown parameter error from Stripe

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, stripe-payments

So i'm trying to set up my Stripe Managed account, and my first step is wanting to actually create the user. I'm using Alamofire in order to create stripe accounts on behalf of my users. This is the code in which I am using to do this:

```
func alamoTest(){
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization":"Bearer tokenxxxxxxxx",
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
    let url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts"
    let params : [String: AnyObject] = ["managed":"true" as AnyObject,"country":"US" as AnyObject]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {(response) in
        print("this is what comes out", response)
        if let data = response.data {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("Response:\(json)")
        }
}

}
```

But now when I send the request I am getting this error, and after searching everywhere online I can't seem to understand what i'm doing wrong, because these are the exact parameters that were put in the Stripe Documentation

```
SUCCESS: {
error =     {
    message = "Received unknown parameter:   {\"Country\":\"US\",\"Managed\":\"true\"}";
    param = "{\"Country\":\"US\",\"Managed\":\"true\"}";
    type = "invalid_request_error";
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because "true" should be a Bool rather than a string? so remove the quotations around true and see if that works.

Comment: no luck =/, I still ended up getting the same thing  SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        message = "Received unknown parameter: {\"managed\":true,\"country\":\"US\"}";
        param = "{\"managed\":true,\"country\":\"US\"}";
        type = "invalid_request_error";
    };
}